# Display Flex Image Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with my image slider. I've looking the whole day to find a solution and I can't fix this problem. I have an image slider which is set to `display: flex`. The problem is when I resize the browser, the current image is not filling the parent container. It moves left and right. You can check out the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2udykpm7/6/) that I made, so you can see the problem. I tried `flex-shrink: 0;`, `object-fit: fill`, cover, etc. and I can't fix it. I don't know what am I doing wrong.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="meh">
   <div id="main-container">
      <div id="slider-container">
         <img src="https://copmec.com/images/headers/header40.jpg" 
         class="img">
         <img src="https://thepunctuationshow.com/rw_common/them
         es/volcano/images/editable_images/1.jpg"                         
         class="img">
         <img src="https://skopelosweb.gr/images/biking.jpg" 
         class="img">
         <img src="https://alphacomputer.rw/images/bannerbg3.jpg" 
         class="img">
      </div>
         <button id="prevBtn">prev</button>
         <button id="nextBtn">next</button>
   </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: green;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#meh {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}
#main-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
  background: red;
}

#slider-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#slider-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

#prevBtn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(50% - 35px);
  padding: 25px 10px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
#nextBtn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: calc(50% - 35px);
  padding: 25px 10px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
#slider-container button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgb(170, 170, 170);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
const container = document.getElementById("slider-container");
const images = document.getElementsByClassName("img");

// Buttons
const prev = document.getElementById("prevBtn");
const next = document.getElementById("nextBtn");

// Counter
let counter = 1;
var size = images[1].clientWidth;


container.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

// Button listeners

next.addEventListener('click', () => {
container.style.transition = "transform 0.5s ease-in-out";
counter++;
container.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
})

prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
container.style.transition = "transform 0.5s ease-in-out";
counter--;
container.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
})
```

Thanks for your help in advance :) And sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in the js code. I added this to your code

```
window.onresize = function(){
   size = images[1].clientWidth;
   container.style.transition = "none";
   container.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
}
```

you need to change the `size` value and the `translation` of the `container`

this is the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2udykpm7/8/)

```js
const container = document.getElementById("slider-container");
const images = document.getElementsByClassName("img");

// Buttons
const prev = document.getElementById("prevBtn");
const next = document.getElementById("nextBtn");

// Counter
let counter = 1;
var size = images[1].clientWidth;

window.onresize = function(){
   size = images[1].clientWidth;
   container.style.transition = "none";
   container.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
}

container.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

// Button listeners

next.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.style.transition = "transform 0.5s ease-in-out";
    counter++;
    container.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
})

prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.style.transition = "transform 0.5s ease-in-out";
    counter--;
    container.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: forestgreen;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#meh {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    
}
#main-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
    background: red;
    
}

#slider-container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#slider-container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

#prevBtn {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: calc(50% - 35px);
    padding: 25px 10px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
#nextBtn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: calc(50% - 35px);
    padding: 25px 10px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
#slider-container button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgb(170, 170, 170);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Image Slider</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="meh">
            <div id="main-container">
                <div id="slider-container">
                    <img src="https://copmec.com/images/headers/header40.jpg" class="img" id="lastClone">
                    <img src="https://thepunctuationshow.com/rw_common/themes/volcano/images/editable_images/1.jpg"                               class="img">
                    <img src="https://skopelosweb.gr/images/biking.jpg" class="img">
                    <img src="https://alphacomputer.rw/images/bannerbg3.jpg" class="img">
                </div>
                <button id="prevBtn">prev</button>
                <button id="nextBtn">next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Zechos I think this is what you are looking for. check the jsfiddle it's better

Comment: Oh wow :d Thank you very much :D this is working just as i wanted :) Thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the width of the container in css change #meh{} :

```
width: 90%;
```

to a fixed value like 300px for example :

```css
#meh {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answers to both of you :)
@Stakvino: But i need my image slider to be responsive. I want it to be wide 90% no matter how i resize the browser..